# MongoDB: Parse file from mongoexport with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoexport

I have exported a mongo collection with `mongoexport` into a file with MongoDB native syntax.

`$ mongoexport --db=pronghorn --collection=testcollection --out ~/test.mongofile`

```
$ cat ~/test.mongofile
{"_id":"id2","name":"name2","passCheck":false, "values":[{"check1":true},{"check2":false}]}
{"_id":"id2","name":"name2","passCheck":true, "values":[{"check1":true},{"check2":true}]}
```

Now, I want to parse the `test.mongofile` with PyMongo and figure out the list of dict key `values`.

Is it possible to parse MongoDB output from file? 
Or can I only get the values by directly send a filter-request to MongoDB server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need answers...

The output is json by default, or rather "extended json"(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/).

You could always parse the output using traditional json tooling, such as the python `json` module:

```py
import json

with open("/path/to/exported/data.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data["values"])
```